# Xamarin swipeview, when you swipe again, it returns to the position of the last. What is this?

Tags: xamarin, swipeview

If you swipe several times on an already opening field, then after closing the swiped element will return to the position from which the last swipe was.

For example:
[image]

I upload project for replay problem: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n5JBYqzAMYr-WPrJH5Dv3g6443-cZXN6/view?usp=sharing)

XAML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestSwipeView.MainPage">
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TestSequence}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItems>
                        <SwipeItem Text="F"
                                   
BackgroundColor="LightGreen"/>
                        <SwipeItem Text="D" 
 BackgroundColor="LightPink"/>
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White"
                      Padding="10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Xaml.cs code:

```
 namespace TestSwipeView
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public List<String> TestSequence { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            TestSequence = new List<string>();
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                TestSequence.Add(String.Format("Test {0}",i));
            }
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I test your project at Google Pixel Android 10, it works fine , can not produce your problem, so suggest you can try to test your project at another device.

Comment: I so sorry, this problem exist on iOS, for example IPhone 7...

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, I find this thread [[Bug] SwipeView Items Lose their Positions when Scrolled & Swiped (iOS)](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13184), maybe you can also create new thread at github to feedback this problem.